# PHP undefined index error in communicating with android

Tags: php, android

I am retrieving data from a database in android so created a php file as below.

```
    <?php

 $db_host  = "localhost";
 $db_uid  = "root";
 $db_pass = "";
 $db_name  = "abc";         
 $db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
 mysql_select_db($db_name);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE  birthyear > '". $_POST["birthyear"]."'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();   
?>
```

Now when i run it in the browser as localhost/script.php
error is thrown and the output is displayed as below

Notice: Undefined index: birthyear in C:\xampp\htdocs\jasonscript.php on line 14
[{"id":"1","name":"m","sex":"1","birthyear":"1989"},{"id":"2","name":"a","sex":"1","birthyear":"1986"},{"id":"3","name":"b","sex":"0","birthyear":"1986"}]

Please tell me how to correct my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$output[]=array("key"=>$row['field_name'],"key1"=>$row['field_name2']);
```

store array like this

Comment: I am fine with the output . need to know why Notice: Undefined index: birthyear in C:\xampp\htdocs\jasonscript.php on line 14 is getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly inserting `$_POST["birthyear"]` in your query which makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Stop doing it right now!

That is also why you get the error. When you directly call the script in your browser, that will be with a GET request and there wont be any POST variables available. So your `$_POST` array wont have a key for `birthyear` and thus it warns you about it.

You should start with something like

```
<?php
$by = isset($_POST["birthyear"]) ? $_POST["birthyear"] : "";
if (empty($by)) {
  echo 'Invalid birthyear';
  exit;
}

//SANITIZE YOUR BIRTHYEAR HERE
//in this case, probaly check for a integer between 1900 and 2100 or something.
//Although just an int could be enough to prevent injection

if (!is_int($by)) {
  echo 'You failed to provide a valid year';
  exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE  birthyear > '". $by."'";

//execute the code 
?>
```

Although the above code is safe, you should check out `bound parameters` like used in [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: +1 definitely should sanitize to avoid them dumping your whole database out inadvertently...

Answer (score 0):

you probably failed to send the values trough post properly.
try `print_r($_POST);` to see what you are actually sending

you still get all results because every year is `> ''`